# Spring MVC Interceptor does not execute for resource handler URLs

Tags: spring-mvc

In the following setup, the TimingInterceptor and CORSHeaders interceptor execute on all URL requests, except for /resources/** URLs. How do I make the interceptors work for /resources/** URLs served by the ResourceHttpRequestHandler?

```
@EnableWebMvc //equivalent to mvc:annotation-driven
@Configuration 
@PropertySource("classpath:configuration.properties") 
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private TimingInterceptor timingInterceptor;

    @Inject
    private CORSHeaders corsHeaders;

    // equivalent to mvc:resources
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");

    }

    // equivalent to mvc:interceptors
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(timingInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**");
        registry.addInterceptor(corsHeaders).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** As of Spring Framework 5.0.1 (and [SPR-16034](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16034)), interceptors are automatically mapped on `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` by default.

I think the configured interceptors aren't mappped on the resource handler, but on the one handling `@RequestMapping` requests.

Maybe try this instead?

```
@EnableWebMvc //equivalent to mvc:annotation-driven
@Configuration 
@PropertySource("classpath:configuration.properties") 
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private TimingInterceptor timingInterceptor;

    @Inject
    private CORSHeaders corsHeaders;

    // equivalent to mvc:resources
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");

    }

    @Bean
    public MappedInterceptor timingInterceptor() {
        return new MappedInterceptor(new String[] { "/**" }, timingInterceptor);
    }

    @Bean
    public MappedInterceptor corsHeaders() {
        return new MappedInterceptor(new String[] { "/**" }, corsHeaders);
    }

}
```

This should be better documented with [SPR-10655](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10655).

Comment: Yes I think you're right. I've tried adding a MappedInterceptor as you've suggested, but the method isn't being called and the interceptor isn't being added into the context.

Comment: I've created a simple example for this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework-issues/tree/master/SPR-10655 - could you take a look at it? If you come up with a repro project with a possible bug, just open a JIRA issue at http://jira.spring.io

Comment: @BrianClozel is using `@EnableWebMvc` and `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` together advisable? The [document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration) says otherwise. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed, this is not recommended for Spring Boot since it turns off auto-configuration for MVC. This question only mentions Spring.

Comment: Thanks @brian-clozel , this is working fine. I have tried it with 2 type of static resources.
1. Static resources like js, images files
2. Asset files which are mapped on a URL served from disk
For asset files I have implemented a ACL using interceptor

Answer (score 0):

I never tried to use Spring interceptors for serving resources. The power of interceptors is to have a *hook* before controller and between controller and view.

To add pre- or post-processing around resources, you'd better use filters.